# Making Ajax request in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have create a ajax request in wordpress and print some li in function for some resone ajax print whole page html in the response can anyone help to find the mistake

Here is Ajax request:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.cat-list_item').on('click', function () {
        $('.cat-list_item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php admin_url('admin- ajax.php') ?>',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                action: 'filter_store',
                category: $(this).data('slug'),
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log("yes" + res);
                $('.project-tiles').html(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hee in mu function in function.php file

```
function load_specialita_ajax_handler() {
 echo "yes";
 exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_store', 'load_specialita_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter_store', 'load_specialita_ajax_handler' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt `echo` ajax URL. Change this line

```
url: '<?php admin_url('admin- ajax.php') ?>',
```

**to**

```
 url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>',
```